# How to combine CGRects with each other in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I was wondering if there was any way to combine a CGRect with another CGRect to get a new CGRect. Does swift have any preset functionality to do this or is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this assume the rects are next to each other? What would be the algorithm/approach for "combining" two rectangles, in a general sense?

Comment: @CraigOtis yes exactly, two CGRects next to each other for example. I'm wondering if its possible to combine the two.

Comment: @rmaddy CGRectUnion: "Returns the smallest rectangle that contains the two source rectangles." I don't think its the right one

Comment: @Zouvv Clarify what you are actually looking for then because I think `CGRectUnion` is what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy I quite simply have two CGRects that appear next to each other, then I want to combine them into one CGRect. but I will try that anyway, thanks

Answer (score 18):

```
let rect1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let rect2 = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 150, height: 150)
let union = rect1.union(rect2) // {x 0 y 0 w 190 h 190}
```

See for more:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cggeometry
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3 and newer:

```
let rect1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let rect2 = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 150, height: 150)
let union = rect1.union(rect2) // {x 0 y 0 w 190 h 190}
```

Result is standardized, so resulting width and height are always positive:

```
let rect3 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: -100, height: -100)
let clone = rect3.union(rect3) // {x -100 y -100 w 100 h 100}
```

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union