# Combine two CGRect

Tags: swift, swift3, cgrect

Is there any way to combine two CGRect?
I want to add "y: 65.0" to an existing CGRect and can't seem to find any way to do it. 
Sounds like a simple task to me but seems impossible to do in Xcode since "+=" isn't allowed between CGRect's.

EDIT: Tried using *offsetBy* and adding them using the following code. When adding the CGRect's i get the error message: `No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGRect'`

```
    var fromRect:CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let addRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 65.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

    //fromRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 65.0)
    fromRect = fromRect + addRect
```

Comment: what does it mean "combine two CGRect"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533937/can-you-combine-cgrects-with-each-other-in-swift ? But I'm not sure if it works for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe you could just implement an operator yourself :

```
func +(left: CGRect, right: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let origin = CGPoint(x: left.origin.x + right.origin.x, y: left.origin.y + right.origin.y)
    let size = CGSize(width: left.size.width + right.size.width, height: left.size.height + right.size.height)
    return CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
}

func +=(left: inout CGRect, right: CGRect) {
    left = left + right
}
```

but there is a simpler solution to that problem without using operators:
Just do this: (I'm not sure about this part because it seems that you want to do something more complex ?)

```
rect.origin.y += 65
```

Comment: What would this operation mean in a 2D plane? There is `CGRectIntegral` which I understand, but this not really.

Comment: This is in the first place a solution to his answer, he can now do rect += CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 0, height: 0)

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't downvote the answer. I think the question is bad.

Comment: But you make me think that there is a simpler solution, I just get influenced by the "+=" in the question to be honest lol

Comment: Used the '+' func and it worked! Thanks @Stormsyders

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to literally add an offset to a rect's position, as in your example of adding y:65, you can use `rect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 64)`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason.

Code i have tried:
var fromRect:CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
let addRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 65.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        
//fromRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 65.0)
romRect = fromRect + addRect

When i'm trying to use the last line of code i get the error "No '+' candidates produce teh extended contextual result type 'CGRect'

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing in your last line. If you are trying to offset a rect by 65 y, then let newRect = fromRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 65.0). You can't use the "+" operator on rects. The offsetBy function can be used to add to the X or Y position of a rect.